# How to output Google QR Code generator result to database?

Tags: php, mysql, qr-code

I want to generate and store QR code image in mysql database in order to send it by e-mail later. I tried the following code:

```
function generateQRCode($person_id)
{
    ob_start();
    $var=file_get_contents("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=$person_id");
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

but `$var` contains bad data.

What are the ways to achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [base64 encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) the output data and store that, then just decode it again before use:

```
$result = base64_encode(file_get_contents("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=$person_id"));
// store $result in your DB
```

Then after retrieving from the database:

```
// get result from your DB
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo base64_decode($dbResult);
```

Comment: okay, that seems to work, however, how do I attach file to the mail?

Comment: I'd suggest you use an extension like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer, but if you want to do it yourself you need to add mime type headers to your `mail()` call. These will expect the image to be base64 encoded already, so you may not need to decode it first.